# sum is added to itself again and again

Tags: arithmetic, pattern-recognition

What do you call a pattern wherein the sum is added to itself over and again?

For example,

$5 + 5 = 10 + 10 = 20 + 20$ and so on

PS
I'm not very familiar with math terms so I'd appreciate a simple answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) with a ratio of $2$

Answer (score 0):

I would call it
successive doubling.